# Probability: Exactly one "tails"

Tags: probability

Consider $3$ coins A, B and C.each coin can have outcome "head" or "tails" with an equal probability of $0.5$. You throw the coins A, B, C one after another. What is the probability that exactly one of the coins shows tails?

Comment: Hint: Binomial distribution.

Comment: Write out all the possible outcomes – there are only eight of them. Identify the favorable outcomes. Work out the probabilities of the favorable outcomes. Report the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use binomial probability $${n \choose k}p^n\left(1-p\right)^{n-k}$$

where $k$ is the number of desired outcomes. I'll assume you know how to use this formula since its a matter of substitution from here.